# (org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' ) while using firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

i am working on a chat app and i want to use the older dependencies but while using it i faced these issues

**Error**

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>       ... 107 more

**Gradle file**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please use a meaningful title and description for your question.

Comment: isn't this issue caused by the gradle file

Comment: @mezohnadhikari try to update all your dependencies to the latest version check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

Also make sure that you use latest version of google-services like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to user the older dependencies .. is there any alternative

Comment: it didn't solved ..  this problem occurs while i try to build the app on my mobile phone..   i even tried restartting the android studio but it didn't solved

Comment: @mezohnadhikari provide us both 2 grandle files and i will help you